# Hackerrank practice challenge showing errors

Tags: language-agnostic

Can anyone just try solving the problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase

I don't want the solution, I just think that it is not showing correct solution even when my code is right. Just tell me if the problem is fine and your solution is running error free.

Comment: This isn't an appropriate post for the site as-is. If you need help, post the question here directly, show your code here (don't link to it), and explain what debugging you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- I don't know what language you're using, but I did that one in Python a couple years ago with no problem.